# filter out space separated row names

Tags: r

I want to filter out rows where the fourth part of the rownames (`$V4`) starts with `u-`

```
> head(miraligner_filterCRC_filterMM)
                                                       100G 100R 106G 106R 122G 122R 124G 124R 126G 126R 134G 134R
hsa-miR-1296-5p TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT 0 0 0 u-CC          23   17   11   21   29   14   16   20   11    1   37   13
hsa-miR-887-3p GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT 0 0 0 d-CTT      3    8    0    4    4    3    2   12   12    3    4    8
hsa-miR-454-3p TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT 0 u-AT 0 0       2    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    2    1    8    2
hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTG 0 u-TG 0 d-C    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    2    2    2
hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTA 0 u-TA 0 d-C    6    6    5    0    3    3    1    4    1    1    8    5
hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTT 0 u-TT 0 d-C   22   41   12   26   25   51    2   25    2   24   91   51
```

my try

```
table(read.table(text=rownames(miraligner_filterCRC_filterMM))$V4=="u-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data

```
x <- c("hsa-miR-1296-5p TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT 0 0 0 u-CC       ", 
       "hsa-miR-887-3p GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT 0 0 0 d-CTT  ", 
       "hsa-miR-454-3p TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT 0 u-AT 0 0   ", 
       "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTG 0 u-TG 0 d-C", 
       "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTA 0 u-TA 0 d-C", 
       "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTT 0 u-TT 0 d-C")
```

Match a "u-" after 3 groups of non-space characters separated by spaces:

```
grep("^(?:[^ ]+ ){3}u-",x,value=TRUE)

# [1] "hsa-miR-454-3p TAGTGCAATATTGCTTATAGGGTAT 0 u-AT 0 0   "
# [2] "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTG 0 u-TG 0 d-C"
# [3] "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTA 0 u-TA 0 d-C"
# [4] "hsa-miR-200b-3p TAATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACTT 0 u-TT 0 d-C"
```

Comment: What if I want to filter an exact match to "u-A"?

Comment: @user2300940 You see that `u-` at the end of the regex? Change it to `u-A`.

Comment: That will filter u-AA as well

Comment: @A.Webb How could I output the other columns as well, not only the ID?

Comment: Use `grep` without the `value=TRUE` and it will return the row number of the match.

Comment: Then it outputs only the row number.

Comment: `your_data_frame[grep("your pattern here",column_to_match),]`

Comment: Last question. How do I define exact matched. Like u-A, without filtering u-AA. Something like u-A$ ??

Comment: Presumably you have a space after it here "u-A ". I would think geneticists would be curious to investigate efficient pattern matching techniques like regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
columnSplitted<- strsplit(miraligner_filterCRC_filterMM$V4,'-')
part1<- unlist(columnSplitted)[2*(1:nrow(miraligner_filterCRC_filterMM))-1]
miraligner_filterCRC_filterMM[part1!="u",]
```